# mongodb full text search negative terms

Tags: php, mongodb, full-text-search, php-mongodb

I'm currently working on a search engine. I do it with php / mongodb.

The new feature [Full Text Search](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/search-for-text/) does quite well a big part of the job, but I have a situation.

Here is an example:
I search `"Pizza -restaurant"` (I'm french, but the words are transparents)

With the negative terms, there is a lot of documents with "restaurant" that are removed.

But there is still 3 or 4 documents with "restaurant" inside.

In these documents, "restaurant" is like any other words. It's separated with space, with no special character. It written in upper-case.
(But the upper-case seems not to be the reason)

If it helps, the debug string is `"[queryDebugString] => pizza||restaur||||"`
And here is an example of a document that is not removed :

```
BAR - RESTAURANT LE ST MICHAL CAMPAGNARD, BAR - RESTAURANT LE ST MICHAL
```

or

```
HOTEL - RESTAURANT rd 1120 19460 auberge de la route SpÃ©cialitÃ©s gastronomiques du terroir
```

Edit : Here is the command to do the search:

```
$result = $this->_dbLocal->command(
            array(
            'text' => 'boutique', //this is the name of the collection where we are searching
                'search' => $q, //the string to search
                // 'language' => 'french',
                'limit' => 500,
        )
    );
```

EDIT : With some test, the negative terms works well with `language: none` in the search and the index. But with `language: none`, my search does not use stop words anymore, which were really useful ...

Is there any way to use stop words for everything but negative terms ? :/

Thank you for your time !

Gilles.

Comment: Are the documents being correctly excluded in the exact same pattern?

Comment: What is the command you're using to do the search? Are you including language?

Comment: neither of those results include the term "pizza". seems like the negation isn't processed.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I've edited the post to show the command. I don't really know about the pattend of the excluded documents. The language is quite difficult for me. If I put "french" in the index & search, there is way less result, and I don't want that :/

Comment: @sambomartin I'm sorry, the text in documents is quite long, so I only posted a sample of it. It does include pizza later.

Comment: Is the search string actually `pizza -restaur` (as the `queryDebugString` you reference is very different)? Do the results chnage if you use `pizza -restaurant`?

Comment: @WiredPrairie my search string is actually `pizza -restaurant`. I think  it's the language with stop words that transform the string.

I will try to set the language to "none".

Comment: No change with `language none` :/

Comment: I've edited my main post !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross-referencing this with the [mongodb-user thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/GBal3rsgueM) on the same issue. This was confirmed as a bug in [SERVER-11994](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11994) and has since been fixed in 2.5.5 and the forthcoming 2.6 release.